# Angular issue : error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 3

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I know there is some issue with the constructor or with the class but i am not sure what's the issue.

My recipe model class looks like this :

```
    export class Recipe{
    public name : string;
    public description :string;
    public imagePath : string;

    contructor(name : string , desc : string , imagePath :string){

        this.name = name;
        this.description = desc;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }
}
```

This is how my recipe-list-component.ts ,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-list',
  templateUrl: './recipe-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-list.component.css']
})
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {

  recipes : Recipe[] = [
    new Recipe('A Test Recipe' , 'This is test' , 'abc.jsp')];
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

[This is how my app structure looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuVYn.jpg)

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this is issue.
I am using Angular CLI: 10.0.5 , Node: 12.18.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in your recipe-model.

It should be constructor, not contructor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a typo error. In Recipe model, it should be constructor instead of contructor.

Please use visual studio code IDE. This will highlight the mistakes in your code.